# Get SharePoint parent ID with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, json

This is my code at the moment.
With this I get the information of a site. And of the requested site I want to get the parent ID.

I found a query: `_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('TaskListName')/items(3)/ParentID`
But this is for a list. and I need it for a site.

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/webs?$select=ServerRelativeUrl,Title,Id,SiteLogoUrl",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {"Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"},
    success: function(subsites) {
                        console.log(subsites)
                var aSites = subsites.d.results;

            $.each(subsites.d.results, function(x,index) {
                getSubSites(this.ServerRelativeUrl, this.Title);

            var sID = (aSites[x].Id);
            var sTitle = (aSites[x].Title);
            var siteLogo = (aSites[x].SiteLogoUrl);
            var sURL = (aSites[x].ServerRelativeUrl);
            var sParent = "Moet nog gemaakt worden";
            console.log("Naam site: " + sTitle);
            console.log("ID: " + sID);
            console.log("URL: " + sURL);
            console.log("Parent: " + sParent);
            console.log("-------------------------------------------")
            var newDIV = jQuery('<tr> <td>' + sTitle + '</td> <td>' + sURL + '</td> <td>' + sID + '</td> <td>' + sParent + '</td> <td><img src="' + siteLogo + '" height="50px" width="50px"></img> ' + siteLogo + '</td></tr>');
                   newDIV.find("table" ).val(newDIV);
                   $('table').append(newDIV);
            }); 
    },
    error: function(subsites) {},
    async: false
});
```

Comment: Hi do you want the Id of the Site

Comment: How do you mean how I want the ID? I want the GUID from the parent site as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below endpoint to get the Id of the parent web:

```
 _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl/_api/web/parentweb?$select=Id
```

Check below screenshot to check the JSON response:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you want the parent site Guid so you can use below rest end point to get Guid:-

//Guid for Site Collection

```
 `url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Site?$select=Id"'
```

//Guid and Title Parent Web

```
`url: _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/ParentWeb?$select=Id,Title"'
```

Comment: If you have site: http:// site.com/sitecol/site1/site2
I want to get the GUID of site 1 when I use the API to get information from site 2